# Is there any limit of time for how long I can drive outside of the country of residence?

Tags: europe, automobiles, regulations

I am wondering if there is any limit on how long I can drive my car outside of Romania (my country of residence), or if there is any limit in any European country on how long I can be there, with my car without having any additional documents (such as registering the car in that country and so on).

Is there any website that centralizes this at level of European Union/European countries?

How can I be sure I can stay for `X` days/weeks/months/years in a place, without having any problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any limit of time for how long I can drive [in any European country] outside my country of residence?

[No limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=European_driving_licence&oldid=1065282427)  for driving in EEA if not moving permanently:

> A driving licence issued by a member state of the EEA is recognised throughout the EEA and can be used as long as it is valid, the driver is old enough to drive a vehicle of the equivalent category, and the licence is not suspended or restricted and has not been revoked in the issuing country. If the holder of an EEA driving licence moves to another EEA country, the licence can be exchanged for a driving licence from the new EEA country. However, as all EEA driving licences are recognised throughout the EEA, it is usually not necessary to exchange it.

https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/vehicles/registration/registration-abroad/index_en.htm:

> Moving on a temporary basis (not changing normal residence): If you move temporarily to another EU country without changing your normal residence  you do not have to register your car or pay any registration taxes there. You can keep your car registered in your country of normal residence.

Note that:

> If you move **permanently** to another EU country and take your car with you, you should register your car and pay car-related taxes in your new country.

Comment: For the registration for the car: 3 months if you are taking up residence in another EU country as an EU citizen. For licence: renewal must be done in the country of residence.

Comment: @MarkJohnson thx yes adding https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/vehicles/registration/registration-abroad/index_en.htm

Answer (score 0):

Within the European Union and European Economic Area, a driving licence from a Member State is always recognized remain valid until their expiry date. If the licence is valid indefinitely and the person has established residence in another Member State for at least two years, an administrative validity of 10 or 5 years since the issuance may apply.

If you established residence in another Member State and need to replace the licence for whatever reason (expired, lost, stolen, damaged) or your licence is suspended/revoked/seized, you will have to obtain one in your country of residence according to the local rules.

More information can found on the [EU website](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/vehicles/driving-licence/driving-licence-exchange-recognition/index_en.htm) (some links to national authorities are broken) and the responsible department's website in each country.

[Switzerland](https://www.ch.ch/en/documents-and-register-extracts/driving-licence/exchanging-your-driving-licence/) has its own rules which require the exchange for a Swiss licence at latest one year after establishing residence, or immediately after establishing residence for driving certain professional vehicles; EU and EEA rules do not apply.

Comment: This answer only addresses the issue of driving licences. However, as the OP intends to drive his car in other countries, he will need insurance cover. Few insurance companies are willing to provide cover for extended trips abroad, and the OP will find it difficult to obtain insurance in countries where he is not a resident.

Comment: @RichardBeasley Yes, I was only touching the driving licensing part since the other answer mentioned registration. But insurance is also a good point that may deserve a separate answer.